# svn working copy issue

Tags: svn, apache

Hi guys I have an easy question, but not easy to me.

I have a repo in /mnt/apps/repos and I would like to do a hook which will update/export everything to /mnt/apps/dev/repos folder but when running:

```
#/usr/bin/svn update /mnt/apps/dev/repos
```

I am getting error:

```
Skipped '/mnt/webapps/dev/repos'
```

when run

```
#usr/bin/svn export /mnt/apps/dev/repos
```

I am getting:

```
svn: '/mnt/webapps/dev/repos' is not a working copy
```

how to add /mnt/webapps/dev/repos as a working copy for all files from repo DB?

please help

Comment: how to add this .svn folder which seems to do trick?

Comment: Is your SVN server on the same machine as the working copy of your repository?

Comment: yes it is, and I woule like to use is for Apache dev purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an URL format to specify your repository, either http://, https://, svn://, svn+ssh:// or file://

The repository is the database for all your versions, so you cannot update it. You probably want to check out a working copy.

```
svn checkout file:///mnt/webapps/dev/repos /home/user/workingcopy
```

Please note that:

- usually you don't check out the root of the repository, it's common to have a /project/trunk layout inside.
- it's advisable to use http(s):// or svn(+ssh):// when using the repository with multiple people for security reasons. It's better to have a server daemon in front of the repository than to allow everyone read/write access to it.
- if `/mnt` indicates that you mounted a network share with the repository on it, **don't** do it that way, go with a server instead

Check out the free [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) for more details

Comment: thanks for that but what if i need working copy to be on this same server in order to make development version under apache?

Comment: ok the svn checkout file:///mnt/webapps/svn/repos /mnt/webapps/dev/repos/ did the trick then I am able to do hook as: svn update /mnt/webapps/dev/repos/ cheers

Comment: You just checked out the repository INTO the repository. I highly recommend you read the book/documentation because this sounds *very* wrong and broken! That's why I told you to use `/home/user/workingcopy` instead.